# Как сделать шестигранник с закруглёнными углами для clip-path?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

У меня есть такой шестигранник с закруглёнными углами. 
Мне нужен точно такой же шестигранник, только повёрнутый на 90 градусов.

Свойством `transform : rotate(Xdeg)` я могу это сделать, но мне нужен сам полигон.

С помошью какой программы я могу создать полигон, с данным форматом координат ?

```css
.hexagon {
  clip-path: polygon(92.32051% 40%, 93.79385% 43.1596%, 94.69616% 46.52704%, 95% 50%, 94.69616% 53.47296%, 93.79385% 56.8404%, 92.32051% 60%, 79.82051% 81.65064%, 77.82089% 84.50639%, 75.35575% 86.97152%, 72.5% 88.97114%, 69.3404% 90.44449%, 65.97296% 91.34679%, 62.5% 91.65064%, 37.5% 91.65064%, 34.02704% 91.34679%, 30.6596% 90.44449%, 27.5% 88.97114%, 24.64425% 86.97152%, 22.17911% 84.50639%, 20.17949% 81.65064%, 7.67949% 60%, 6.20615% 56.8404%, 5.30384% 53.47296%, 5% 50%, 5.30384% 46.52704%, 6.20615% 43.1596%, 7.67949% 40%, 20.17949% 18.34936%, 22.17911% 15.49361%, 24.64425% 13.02848%, 27.5% 11.02886%, 30.6596% 9.55551%, 34.02704% 8.65321%, 37.5% 8.34936%, 62.5% 8.34936%, 65.97296% 8.65321%, 69.3404% 9.55551%, 72.5% 11.02886%, 75.35575% 13.02848%, 77.82089% 15.49361%, 79.82051% 18.34936%);
  background: #c3797c;
  width: 12vw;
  height: 12vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="hexagon"></div>
```

Скажите пожалуйста как можно создать polygon для clip-path с закруглёнными краями ?

Comment: На svg у меня есть они.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если У Вас уже есть точки, образующие желаемую фигуру, повернуть вокруг какой-то точки их можно при помощи `javascript` по этой формуле:

```
x1 = (cos * (x - cx)) + (sin * (y - cy)) + cx, 
y1 = (cos * (y - cy)) - (sin * (x - cx)) + cy;
```

```js
let p = `92.32051% 40%, 93.79385% 43.1596%, 94.69616% 46.52704%, 95% 50%, 94.69616% 53.47296%, 93.79385% 56.8404%, 92.32051% 60%, 79.82051% 81.65064%, 77.82089% 84.50639%, 75.35575% 86.97152%, 72.5% 88.97114%, 69.3404% 90.44449%, 65.97296% 91.34679%, 62.5% 91.65064%, 37.5% 91.65064%, 34.02704% 91.34679%, 30.6596% 90.44449%, 27.5% 88.97114%, 24.64425% 86.97152%, 22.17911% 84.50639%, 20.17949% 81.65064%, 7.67949% 60%, 6.20615% 56.8404%, 5.30384% 53.47296%, 5% 50%, 5.30384% 46.52704%, 6.20615% 43.1596%, 7.67949% 40%, 20.17949% 18.34936%, 22.17911% 15.49361%, 24.64425% 13.02848%, 27.5% 11.02886%, 30.6596% 9.55551%, 34.02704% 8.65321%, 37.5% 8.34936%, 62.5% 8.34936%, 65.97296% 8.65321%, 69.3404% 9.55551%, 72.5% 11.02886%, 75.35575% 13.02848%, 77.82089% 15.49361%, 79.82051% 18.34936%`;

let rotatePoint = (pt, rad, cx, cy) => pt.trim()
    .split('%')
    .map(s => s.trim()).filter(s => s)
    .map((coord, i, arr) => i ? 
          (Math.cos(rad)*(arr[1]-cy))-(Math.sin(rad)*(arr[0]-cx))+cy:
          (Math.cos(rad)*(arr[0]-cx))+(Math.sin(rad)*(arr[1]-cy))+cx)
    .join('% ') + '%'; 
    
requestAnimationFrame(draw)

function draw(t){
  let clip = p.split(',').map(pt => rotatePoint(pt, -(t/33)/180*Math.PI, 50, 50)).join(',');
  hexagon.style.clipPath = `polygon(${clip})`;
  requestAnimationFrame(draw)
}
```

```css
#hexagon {
  background: #c3797c;
  width: 90vh;
  height: 90vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="hexagon"></div>
```